# Assigning values to Array Gets Slow after many Values

Tags: arrays, performance, for-loop, autoit

I'm assigning different parts of a csv to an array, particularly 2 per line, and they're not big values, instead they are just lat/longs with 6 values after the decimal. Sometimes I can have a list of 500 lines, and sometimes it can have up to 100,000 lines. When it gets above about 4,000 however the code begins to get very slow. I have a progress bar that shows the progress, so I can see that it is getting exponentially slower as it is assigning the values. Here is my code:

```css
$aArray1 = FileReadToArray("\\miami\edx\requests\"&$FileName&"\Data\GIS\Meters.csv")

For $i = 2 to Ubound($aArray1)
   $line = FileReadLine("\\miami\edx\requests\"&$FileName&"\Data\GIS\Meters.csv", $i)
          $row_array = StringSplit($line,",")

   $lattitude[$i] = $row_array[Ubound($row_array)-3]
   $longitude[$i] = $row_array[Ubound($row_array)-2]

   GUICtrlSetData($progress1, ($i/ubound($aArray1))*100)
   GUICtrlSetData($Label2,Round(($i/ubound($aArray1))*100,1)&"% Complete")
Next
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be getting so slow? Maybe I'm repeating unneccesary steps every time and that's slowing it down. I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you reading the whole file into an array, then reading the file again line by line. That appears it would make it slow to me. Why not use the same array you created at the top to do what you need?

Comment: @Panama Jack I read it at the beginning to get the upper bound. That was used for the progress bar. I don't see why that would really slow anything down, as it is the for loop that gets slow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Panama jack, I figured it out. I just used the original array I made instead of reading each line. I still don't know what was slowing it down so much, but here's what fixed it:

```css
$i = 2
$aArray1 = FileReadToArray("\\miami\edx\requests\"&$FileName&"\Data\GIS\Meters.csv")
Do
   $row_array = StringSplit($aArray1[$i],",")

   $lattitude[$i] = $row_array[Ubound($row_array)-3]
   $longitude[$i] = $row_array[Ubound($row_array)-2]

   GUICtrlSetData($progress1, ($i/ubound($aArray1))*100)
   GUICtrlSetData($Label2,Round(($i/ubound($aArray1))*100,1)&"% Complete")
   $i = $i + 1
Until $i = Ubound($aArray1)
```

Comment: Good job, I was just about to give an example of what I meant by reusing the same array. And the reason it's slow is because you are reading it line by line on every iteration. From the autoit help file. `From a performance standpoint it is a bad idea to read line by line specifying "line" parameter whose value is incrementing by one. This forces AutoIt to reread the file from the beginning until it reach the specified line.`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <file.au3>
$file = "C:\Users\test\meters.csv"
Local $aArray
_FileReadToArray($file, $aArray, 1, ",")
_ArrayDisplay($aArray,"Debug")
$lattCol=6 ; adapt to your actual array, obviously
; $lattCol=$aArray[0][1]-3 ; counting from end 
$longCol=7

For $i = 1 To $aArray[0][0]
    ConsoleWrite($aArray[$i][$lattCol] & "   -   " & $aArray[$i][$longCol] & @CRLF)
    ConsoleWrite("prgress1: " & $i / $aArray[0][0] * 100 & @CRLF)
    ConsoleWrite("Label2: " & Round($i / $aArray[0][0] * 100,1) & "% complete" & @CRLF)
Next
```

Main change: use `_FileReadToArray` instead of `FileReadToArray` - it has more options (like defining the delimiter(s)), enabling us to work with just one array. (I didn't bother with the GUI-Elements - should be trivial)